# Chrome Extension Inject Script Into Error Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a router that uses HTTP, but it redirects me to HTTPS. On the HTTPS site it refuses the connection. I have a fix: if I go back to the previous page, it loads HTTP correctly.
How can I make a chrome extension that does this?

I already have a manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Zyxel Blocker",
  "description": "Blocks your Zyxel Router from redirecting you to HTTPS",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["webNavigation", "tabs", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://192.168.0.1/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://192.168.0.1/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.error === "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED") {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: details.tabId },
      files: ["content.js"],
    });
  }
});
```

content.js:

```
window.history.back();
```

But now it gives the error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Frame with ID 0 is showing error page

How can I fix my code or is there another way to do this?

Thanks,
JxxIT

Comment: Extensions can't inject into an error page.

Comment: Oh, is there any other way to do this?